# encode and decode a base64 .p12 file

Tags: ssl, certificate

so i want to encode and later decode a .p12 file.

the decoded version is supposed to serve to construct

```
openssl pkcs12 -in my.signed.p12 -cacerts -nokeys -legacy > caCerts
openssl pkcs12 -in my.signed.p12 -nocerts -nodes -legacy > clientKey
openssl pkcs12 -in my.signed.p12 -nokeys -chain -legacy > clientCert
```

however when i try to use the generated keys i get

```
error:05800074:x509 certificate routines::key values mismatch
```

when i diff the certificate i have which works and my generated one they missmatch. what is the reason for that?

Comment: `-cacerts` should be (as the name implies) used to produce `caCerts`, not `clientCert`. For `clientCert` you should use `-clcerts` (as the name implies). Please see [the documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/openssl-pkcs12.html) which has also examples.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich hi thx for the hint. the first comment seems to be a lack of concentration on my side while writing the question, but i actually had that point correct. the comment about clientCert works in both cases i guess mine and yours should both produce a valid clientCert

Comment: Works for me when I do this with my own .p12 and then using cert and key in `openssl s_server`. Unfortunately neither your p12 is known nor the command you use which results in the error you show.